# Django max_length value for a character verying row

Tags: django, postgresql, varchar

So I have this pre-existing database that I'm trying to connect to using Django and I've already introspected the database and I'm just cleaning up the models before actually doing anything, and I've run into a roadblock. One of the database tables has a row:

> "name" character varying NOT NULL

and when I've run `python manage.py syncdb`, I get the following error:

> app.artistname: "name": CharFields require a "max_length" attribute that is a positive integer.

So I went into models.py to find out what the problem is, and I see:

> name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=-1)

So my question is, what value should I set max_length to if not even the definition in the database has a value set? Do I just set it to the maximum possible value?

Comment: @agf: Sizeless varying is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: @agf: That seemed to do the trick, thanks! :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a field of varying length, you can use a [`TextField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield) instead of a [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) so you don't have to set a size.

Both varying length fields and `TextField`s are generally intended for large amounts of text.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it to a reasonably high value as would be expected for the application. Names... usually 80 characters would suffice unless you have reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: if this was a `mysql` question involving `innodb` i would say 255 characters because that is the limit of what can be indexed but we're talking postgres here.